# link taking me to directory due to htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, directory, file-extension

When I click on a specific link it takes me to the directory file listing, rather then the file its supposed to be.

```
Click link -> Should go to: mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions.php (A list page of exhibitions)
Takes me to ->mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions/ (Directory overview)
```

Right my direcory listing is

```
mysite.co.uk/services/
mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions.php
mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions/exhibitions1.php
mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions/exhibitions2.php
```

I know its to do with my .htaccess  which removes the file extension, I need this but I don't know how to get around the problem. Any ideas?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

The final url should look like this     mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions/exhibitions1

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +Indexes
AcceptPathInfo Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

# Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
   <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
   </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
   </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

 # BEGIN Turn ETags Off
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None 

# BEGIN Remove Last-Modified Header
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>

#ErrorCodes
ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.co.uk/404

# force non-www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Is this the only rule OR there are more rules there?

Comment: Nope, I've got compression, redirects and a few other bits, let em add them in. Although I'm pretty sure its due to this rule.

Comment: ok sure try rule in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule for PHP extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This hasn't worked unfortuantly, gives me a multiple choice problem

Comment: What exactly is this `multiple choice problem`. Can you provide details what didn't work and what URL did you try?

Comment: I've not got rid of the multiple choice problem, but I'm back to square one, i've now disbabled directory listings. i click on the address mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions.php and it takes me to mysite.co.uk/services/exhibitions/ which a normal user an error because they don't have access to it anymore.

Comment: Well if `/exhibitions.php` is becoming `/exhibitions` in browser then you haven't shown all the rules. Place your complete .htaccess in your question and see if you have any additional .htaccess as well.

Comment: I have seen that but currently there is rule to redirect: `/services/exhibitions.php` => `/services/exhibitions` in the browser. Is there any .htaccess isn `/services/` directory also?